# send key/value pairs from asp.net td to jquery and deserialize json

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have JournalRep class  and I have asp.net elementsand same DB entity

I have @model Act. Act entitiy contains JournalRep entity

```
foreach {... in JournalRep ){
<td>
  <input id="@item.ID" type="text" class="PriceWork form-control" value="@item.Price" style="width: 75px;">
</td> ...
}
```

I want to send data to jQuery function and then to C# Controller using id of JournalRep  and Price value. I want to set key/value pair for each  where key is `JournalRep.id` and value is `JournalRep .price`
How can I store data? What is the best way?

I have button outside loop

```
<td style="padding-top:1em;padding-left:6em">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Set Price by hand" onclick="processMyData(@Model.ID)" style="border-color:#2774bd" />
                    </td>
```

Func CalculateWorkHand
I want to add all values of Pricework class and all Id to array datadict

```
    function processMyData(act, priceWorkData) {
    var priceWorkData= {};
$(".PriceWork").each(function() {
    var price = this.value;
    var myId = this.id
    priceWorkData[myId] = price;
});
    var jsonstring= {
          priceWorkData: priceWorkData
         };     

var link = "/Acts/CalculateWorkHand?id=" + act + "&priceWorkData=" + jsonstring;
GoToLink(link);
}
```

**How to pass hash array to controller?**

```
public ActionResult CalculateWorkHand(string act, string json)
{

**// how to deserialize json hashset here? and use it like hashset**

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));


    int itemID= Convert.ToInt32(jsondata["itemID"]);
    double itemPrice=Convert.ToDouble(jsondata["itemPrice"]) /// this is array and not variable
```

//////////////////????????????????????????

```
}
```

what should I do if I pass json hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am assuming that you would only require to hit your `Controller` method on some event. Regarding your case, I would do something like this:

```
foreach {... in JournalRep ){
<td>
  <input id="@item.ID" type="text" class="PriceWork form-control" value="@item.Price" style="width: 75px;" onclick="processMyData(@item.ID,@item.Price)">
</td> ...
}
```

And I would use `AJAX` to send these values to my `Controller` method:

```
<script>
 function processMyData(itemID,itemPrice) {

  //Now generate your JSON data here to be sent to the server
  var json = {
              itemID: itemID,
              itemPrice : itemPrice
             };

   //Send the JSON data via AJAX to your Controller method
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("ProcessMyData", "Home")',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { "json": JSON.stringify(json)},
        success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                  console.log("Success");
                 }
                else {
                 console.log("Some Error");
                }
        },
        error: function (error) {
             console.log(error)
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

And your `Controller` method would look like:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
public ActionResult ProcessMyData(string json)
{
    try
    {
       var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));

        //Get your variables here from AJAX call
        int itemID= Convert.ToInt32(jsondata["itemID"]);
        double itemPrice=Convert.ToDouble(jsondata["itemPrice"])

        if(itemID > 0)
        {
            //Process your variables here
            bool result = DoSomethingWithMyData(itemID,itemPrice);

            //Handle result as required
            if(result==true)
            {
                return Json(new{success = true}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new{success = false}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }                  
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new{success = false}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }               
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new{success = false}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Since you require that your data should be made for all elements, you would need to create a data structure to hold this data. The best data structure here would be a `Dictionary` that will hold your data. You can do something like this in your Javascript code:

```
var priceWorkData= {};
$(".PriceWork").each(function() {
    var price = this.value;
    var myId = this.id
    priceWorkData[myId] = price;
});
```

You can then check if your Dictionary has the correct data like this:

```
for(elementid in priceWorkData) {
    var data= priceWorkData[elementid];
    console.log(data);
}
```

If everything looks good, then you can simply serialize your `priceWorkData` in your `AJAX` call like this:

```
  var json = {
              priceWorkData: priceWorkData
             };
```

And then use the method in my answer to process your `priceWorkData` dictionary in your `Controller`.

I hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202589/discussion-on-answer-by-rahul-sharma-send-key-value-pairs-from-asp-net-td-to-jqu).

Comment: I need to make next question cause you fully answer my first title. big thanks! but deserializing is next theme